# Import CSV file without delimiter - VB.net

Tags: vb.net, csv

I am new to VB.net so excuse me if this is supposed to be a very simple point.
I have an excel file of 1 column and has values as below:

> 1111
>   2222
>   3333
>   4444

When i save it as CSV i get each row on new line without any separator/delimiter.

The difficulty i am facing is that when i loop in the data i only get the first row because obviously i can't seem to identify which delimiter i should use.

How can i import that CSV file and use it's value in a loop or datatable?

Thanks for your time and assistance.

Comment: You need to clarify (like add the code which 'loops the data')..  CSV stands for Comma Separated Values: the comma separates individual values for a Row - you have one value per row, so no comma is needed.

Comment: Perfectly said @Plutonix. So i assume you are saying, no delimiter should be used since they are already separated without the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely it is using carriage returns or line feeds to separate the data, which would separate out using something like this

```
Dim sLines() As String = sFileData.Split(vbCr)
```

or

```
    Dim sLines() As String = sFileData.Split(vbLf)
```

or still yet as Andrew suggested.

```
Dim sLines() as String = File.ReadAllLines(sFilePath)
```

Comment: You might want to suggest the [File.ReadAllLines Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead ;)

Comment: Yes that would work as well, just to illustrate what is separating the data I used Split, but you are very correct.